# CPU 100% usage when login as admin

Tags: memory

When a normal user open my site nothing happens, but when i log into my admin area, each page I open even in admin area or in my site, I see 50-100% cpu usage.
why?!
I disabled cron jobs
I disabled heatbeat
I have cache plugin
and I checked every plugin

Comment: CPU usage on the server? Can you check which process is using the CPU - i.e. it's definitely a web server or PHP worker process? or is it the database?  - and can you check if there are still open ports from your client to the server?

Comment: it's index.php file

Comment: admin/index.php? (which is separate from the index.php in the WordPress root that runs the non-admin site) Does the admin site work, at normal speed - it's not that pages are just taking a very long time to process? If you're sure it's not code added by any of your plugins then it's probably worth checking nothing has modified your admin site code e.g. try making a brand new install of WordPress on the same server and see if that has the problem too, and if not compare the admin folders on both installations for differences.

Comment: And the last part of my first question is still relevant: can you check if there are open ports from your client to the server? i.e. is the CPU load because it's still processing a page of some sort to serve it back to your browser? (and if you can find the complete URL, not just index.php, then that would be awesome too)